# my file is not added in the folder [DRIVE API]

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-drive-api

I am updating with AJAX the name of the file and in which folder it should be saved, the name is updated but the place destined to save (the folder) does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
url: "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/D5Rs1c...",
data: JSON.stringify({
name: "name the drive",
parents: [{
kind: "drive#parentReference",
id: "1isO7RhgpuvNo-dkC0UJLrziGC..."
}]
}),
contentType: "application/json",
type: "PATCH"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your endpoint of `url: "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/D5Rs1c...",`, it seems that you are using Drive API v3. In this case, the filename and folder of the metadata are `name: "samplename"` and `parents: ["folderId"]`, respectively.

But, in order to move the file using Drive API, the destination folder ID is set as a query parameter instead of the request body. So, in your request body, it becomes `JSON.stringify({name: "name the drive"})`. And, the endpoint is required to be changed to `"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + fileId + "?addParents=" + dstFolderId`. I think that this is the reason for your current issue. So, please modify your request body as follows.

From `I am updating with AJAX`, I prepared a sample script with ajax as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
const fileId = "###"; // Please set your file ID of the file you want to update.
const dstFolderId = "###"; // Please set the destination folder ID of the folder you want to put.
const accessToken = "###"; // Please set your access token.

$.ajax({
  method: "PATCH",
  url: "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + fileId + "?addParents=" + dstFolderId,
  data: JSON.stringify({ name: "name the drive" }),
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken,
  }
})
  .done(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
  })
  .fail(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
  });
```

#### Note:

- If your folder of folder ID is in the shared Drive, please add a query parameter of `supportsAllDrives=true` to the endpoint.

#### Reference:

- [Files: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update)

Comment: error: The parents field is not directly writable in update requests. Use the addParents and removeParents parameters instead

Comment: @code2018 Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your reply, I updated the answer. Please confirm it.